# nixos: KDE powermanagement does not have brightness control

Tags: x11, kde-plasma, nixos

I can't control screen brightness in KDE(power management is enabled, but I don't see the brightness control in the power management widget. The brightness keys used to work as well, but now they aren't). I'm on the unstable channel, it was working in the 19.03 release

Battery and brightness settings (Power management widget)
[image: power management widget]

Powerdevil, upower seem to be running without errors, although on startup

This seems relevant -

```
journalctl -xb | grep brightness
Oct 09 08:47:25 blackbox kernel: thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
Oct 09 08:47:25 blackbox kernel: thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
Oct 09 08:47:43 blackbox xsession[1343]: invalid metadata "/run/current-system/sw/lib/qt-5.12.3/plugins/powerdevilkeyboardbrightnesscontrolaction_config.so"
Oct 09 08:47:43 blackbox xsession[1343]: invalid metadata "/run/current-system/sw/lib/qt-5.12.3/plugins/powerdevilbrightnesscontrolaction_config.so"
Oct 09 08:47:45 blackbox xsession[1343]: powerdevil: Falling back to helper to get brightness
Oct 09 08:47:45 blackbox xsession[1343]: powerdevil: "DBus Backend error: service start org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper failed: Bus name not found in system service directory"
```

System information

```
nix-info
system: "x86_64-linux",
multi-user?: yes, 
version: nix-env (Nix) 2.3,
channels(root):
"nixos-20.03pre196201.07d4df59626, home-manager, nixos-hardware"
```

```
neofetch --stdout
xxx@blackbox
-----------------
OS: NixOS 20.03pre196201.07d4df59626 (Markhor) x86_64
Host: 20KGSBP200 ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th
Kernel: 4.19.75
Uptime: 1 day, 4 hours, 16 mins
Packages: 1005 (nix-system), 1152 (nix-user)
Shell: zsh 5.7.1
Resolution: 2560x1440
DE: Plasma
WM: KWin
Theme: Breeze [GTK2]
Icons: breeze [GTK2]
CPU: Intel i5-8350U (8) @ 3.600GHz
Memory: 3920MiB / 15919MiB
```

Comment: A workaround is to just specifically install powerdevil which installs a different version of the package that works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by uninstalling the Nvidia proprietary driver for the GPU and used the open source Linux driver instead.